# How to use ember.js without module support

Tags: javascript, ember.js, compatibility, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

The guides for ember.js are assuming one has the full ES6 support e.g. http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/ shows using the `export default` construct and doesn't specify any alternative way to achieve the goals. However the module feature is not implemented in all browsers that ember is supporting.

How can I use these features with a browser that doesn't support modules? How would the code in these examples translate to ES5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation assumes you are using a transpiling tool, because the recommended tool, [`ember-cli`](http://ember-cli.com/) does. Unless you have good reasons not to use it, you definitely should look into it.

It is, however, perfectly fine to work without it. For instance, without a module system, Ember will map `controller:posts.index` to `App.PostsIndexController`. So this should work for the example you linked:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('favorite-posts');
});

App.FavoritePostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.query('post', { favorite: true });
  }
});
```

You may also use Ember with your own module support. I successfully have an Ember project based on [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/). It does require a bit more work though, to have the [resolver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html) find your classes (that resolver link also documents how ember relates does the name mapping). Nothing hard, but you must build a short script to generate registrations.

---

**Edit for blessenm:** Ember with rollup

Unfortunately I cannot share this code, but it works like this:

1. A script scans the project directory and compiles templates by invoking `ember-template-compiler.js` on every `.hbs` file it encounters.
2. A script (the same one, actually) scans the project directory and generates the main entry point. It's pretty simple, if it sees, say `gallery/models/collection.js` and `gallery/routes/picture.js', it will generate a main file that looks like this:

   ```
   import r1 from 'gallery/models/collection.js';
   import r2 from 'gallery/routes/picture/index.js';
   // ...
   Ember.Application.initializer({
       name: 'registrations',
       initialize: function (app) {
           app.register("model:collection", r1);
           app.register("route:picture.index", r2);
           // ...
       }
   });
   ```

   It should just map your filenames to resolver names. As a bonus, you get to control how your directories are organized.
3. Invoke rollup on the generated file. It will pull everything together. I use IIFE export format, skipping all the run-time resolution mess. I suggest you setup [rollup to work with babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel) so you can use ES6 syntax.

I don't use any ember-specific module, but it should not be too hard to add. My guess is it's mostly a matter of setting up rollup import resolution properly. For all I know, it may work out of the box.

Comment: do you have ur code on github? Just wanted to see how you got it to work with rollup.

Comment: @blessenm I edited the answer with more details on how that works. Unfortunately that project is not public so I can't show the code itself. I hope it helps anyway. You may also want to read [this post](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/can-i-use-ember-with-npm-and-webpack/9160/9) on Ember forum. You might also look at how [this project](https://github.com/tulios/ember-webpack-example) integrates an Ember project using webpack. Different tools, but same approach.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Will go through them and figure it out. I wanted to know what noticeable benefits you had by using rollup? Was ur build output size compared to using ember-cli?

Comment: Taking control of the build process was the main reason. It integrates better within our global workflow, in which the Ember app is just a piece along others. The core project is in python, and assets are handled in python as well (and in fact the script I wrote for Ember is in python, invoking `nodejs` for key steps). Like a lot of JS projects, ember-cli assumes it controls everything, and does not have a clean solution for integrating with the rest of the world. That's why I chose to do the integration myself.

Comment: …(continued) Now, on the JS side, output size ~10% smaller and starts faster thanks to the simplicity of IIFE format, and the fact that name resolution is done at build time, not at runtime. With hundreds of files, all the internal define/require do add up. You lose the incremental build feature but, on the other hand, building 500+ files comes under 1 second on my laptop with rollup. Still, I insist the main reason was the build process. Other benefits are minor and largely outweighed by the convenience ember-cli would have offered.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using Ember CLI http://ember-cli.com/

You write your code in ES6 and it transpiles down to ES5.